# How to pass authorization token with Swagger

Tags: swagger, powerapps

I'm working on creating a custom connector in PowerApps which needs to call an API.  The API needs an authorization token passed.  Sending the request via Postman, this is set as follows:
**Authorization: Bearer 2b3fdha04a4d89aad9c263d5d716bcc379aff0008**

When I try to do the same thing via Swagger, the header gets sent like this:
**Access-Control-Request-Headers: Authorization**

This is how I'm trying to pass the token:

```
      - {name: Authorization, in: header, description: This is the API key, required: true, type: string}
```

And this is my complete Swagger definition file:
`

```
swagger: '2.0'
info: {version: 1.0.0, title: ACME Corp, description: ACME sample API}
host: acmeapis.com
basePath: /
schemes: [https]
consumes: [multipart/form-data]
produces: [application/json]
securityDefinitions: {}
paths:
  /v4_server/external/v1/authenticate:
    post:
      summary: Authorize
      description: Used to get an authorization token
      operationId: Authorize
      parameters:
      - {in: formData, name: api_key, type: string, description: The API key., required: true}
      - {in: formData, name: client_db, type: string, description: The database to use.,
        required: true}
      - {in: formData, name: username, type: string, description: The username, required: true}
      responses:
        default:
          description: All is well
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              access_token: {type: string, description: access_token}
              expires_in: {type: integer, format: int32, description: expires_in}
              refresh_token: {type: string, description: refresh_token}
  /v4_server/external/v1/maintenance/resources/properties:
    get:
      summary: Building/Property Location
      - Bearer: []
      description: Building/Property Location
      operationId: Building_propertyLocation
      parameters:
      - {name: property_use_id, default: '2', in: query, type: string, required: true}
      - {name: $orderBy, default: unit, in: query, type: string, required: true}
      - {name: Authorization, in: header, description: This is the API key, required: true, type: string}
      responses:
        '200': {description: Will send `Authenticated`}
        '403': {description: 'You do not have necessary permissions for the resource,'}
        default:
          description: default
          schema: {}
  /: {}
definitions: {}
parameters: {}
responses: {}
security: []
tags: []
```

`

I can't find any examples on how to do this.  Can someone point me the way.

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines under the schema

```
securityDefinitions:
  Bearer:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
    description: >-
     Enter the token with the `Bearer: ` prefix, e.g. "Bearer abcde12345".
```

Here is your full swagger (I've tested it on [swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) - just copy and past into it to see the result)

```
swagger: '2.0'
info: {version: 1.0.0, title: ACME Corp, description: ACME sample API}
host: acmeapis.com
basePath: /
schemes: [https]
securityDefinitions:
  Bearer:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
    description: >-
      Enter the token with the `Bearer: ` prefix, e.g. "Bearer abcde12345".
consumes: [multipart/form-data]
produces: [application/json]
paths:
  /v4_server/external/v1/authenticate:
    post:
      summary: Authorize
      description: Used to get an authorization token
      operationId: Authorize
      parameters:
      - {in: formData, name: api_key, type: string, description: The API key., required: true}
      - {in: formData, name: client_db, type: string, description: The database to use.,
        required: true}
      - {in: formData, name: username, type: string, description: The username, required: true}
      responses:
        default:
          description: All is well
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              access_token: {type: string, description: access_token}
              expires_in: {type: integer, format: int32, description: expires_in}
              refresh_token: {type: string, description: refresh_token}
  /v4_server/external/v1/maintenance/resources/properties:
    get:
      summary: Building/Property Location
      description: Building/Property Location
      operationId: Building_propertyLocation
      parameters:
      - {name: property_use_id, default: '2', in: query, type: string, required: true}
      - {name: $orderBy, default: unit, in: query, type: string, required: true}
      - {name: Authorization, in: header, description: This is the API key, required: true, type: string}
      responses:
        '200': {description: Will send `Authenticated`}
        '403': {description: 'You do not have necessary permissions for the resource,'}
        default:
          description: default
          schema: {}
  /: {}
definitions: {}
parameters: {}
responses: {}
security: []
tags: []
```

Comment: Thanks Avi.  I tried that, but still not seeing the Authorization Bearer in the get request.  And I was getting a warning that the security scheme was defined by never used, so I appended "      security: 
      - Bearer: []" in the get method.  Still didn't see the headers being sent.  Any other ideas?